# Invalid command code with sed

Tags: sed, osx

This is the command I am using:

```
system_profiler | sed -n -e '/SATA/SATA Express:/,/Software:/ p'
```

It gives me this error

```
sed: 1: "/SATA/SATA Express:/,/S ...": invalid command code S
```

I don't see why it doesn't work especially when this almost identical command works:

```
system_profiler | sed -n -e '/Hardware Overview:/,/Installations:/ p'
```

I don't know? There's no reason to escape S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the `/` between `SATA` and `SATA Express:` to make it literal:

```
system_profiler | sed -n -e '/SATA\/SATA Express:/,/Software:/ p'
```

or use a different delimiter using this syntax:

```
system_profiler | sed -n -e '\|SATA/SATA Express:|,/Software:/ p'
```

Comment: personally, i'd use `=` as delimiter here because a) my first choice `:` is in the input text, and b) you don't have to escape `=` with `\`` as you're doing for `|`.

Comment: @cas Yeah..good one..

Comment: damn comment quoting.  i meant escape with `\\`.  doesn't seem any way to get \ to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Hardware Overview:/,/Installations:/ p
```

This code says: print all the lines between the one that matches `Hardware Overview:` and the one that matches `Installations:`.

The second code doesn't mean anything: you can't put `SATA Express:/` after an address. `sed` awaits a command there, or comma followed by another address. What are you trying to achieve?